# JHipster not adding field search capabilities

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

As mentioned in the documentation, if we use Elasticsearch, JHipster shall create search capabilities for Angular/React UIs. I have tried both of them but search by fields is not added in any screens. I have put the entities in filter and search ... with elasticsearch list in JDL. Tried everything, but it's not generating. Can somebody please list down the steps to include search by entity fields in listing screens. May be I am missing something. I am following documentation, no change in the code, so far everything is in default condition.

Comment: Could you share your JDL? The search form is just one input text and 2 buttons above the table. Maybe you expect something else, here is an example of what you should see https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/bank-account/bank-account.component.html#L14-L24

Comment: I am expecting something like section rectangled in red https://ibb.co/HC922NQ When we include entities in filter section of JDL, search by field capabilities are available in REST API thus swagger too. Search section must be generated for angular/react UI too.

Comment: Entity filtering is not related to Elasticsearch, it's implemented using JPA criteria API and metamodel and this is what you see in swagger. As far as I know, there is no UI generated for entity filtering.

Comment: Docs says 'When the entity sub-generator is used, the generated entity gets automatically indexed by Elasticsearch, and is used in the REST endpoint. Search capabilities are also added to the Angular/React user interface, so you can search your entity in the main CRUD screen.'

Comment: As said above, you're mixing 2 unrelated features in JHipster: search and filtering. Elasticsearch is for full text search and the generated UI is the one I showed you: one single input text for all the entity, not input text per entity field. You don't need Elatiscsearch for filtering but there's no UI generated

Comment: OK got it. Any work around to generate this, otherwise manual update of around 50 screens would be needed

Comment: Write a jhipster module or blueprint, or contribute to JHipster